# css table issue

Tags: html, css

How do I stop the table from pushing when the comment field has lots of text, table code below, **edit: forgot to mention this is a datatable from http://datatables.net/**

[image]

```
    <div id="comment_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid"><div class="dataTables_filter" id="comment_filter"><label>Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="comment"></label></div><table id="comment" class="dataTable" aria-describedby="comment_info">
      <thead>
      <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 60px; " aria-label=""></th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="comment" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 55px; " aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">Name</th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="comment" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 4702px; " aria-label="Comment: activate to sort column ascending">Comment</th><th class="sorting_desc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="comment" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 60px; " aria-sort="descending" aria-label="Created: activate to sort column descending">Created</th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="comment" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 77px; " aria-label="Attachments: activate to sort column ascending">Attachments</th><th class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 46px; " aria-label="&lt;center&gt;Delete?&lt;/center&gt;"><center>Delete?</center></th></tr>
    </thead>

  <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><tr class="odd">
      <td class=" ">
      <img alt="Google-qr-code" height="50" src="/uploads/user/avatar/1/google-qr-code.jpg" width="50">
      </td>
      <td class=" ">Ahmet2</td>
      <td style="overflow: auto;" class=" ">fdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddfdssssssssssssssssssfsddddddddddddv</td>
      <td class="  sorting_1">2012-03-21 13:43:53</td>
      <td class=" "></td>
      <td class=" "><center><a href="/companies/12/comments/48" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Delete" height="15px" src="/assets/delete.png"></a></center></td>
    </tr><tr class="even">
      <td class=" ">
      <img alt="Google-qr-code" height="50" src="/uploads/user/avatar/1/google-qr-code.jpg" width="50">
      </td>
      <td class=" ">Ahmet2</td>
      <td style="overflow: auto;" class=" ">test</td>
      <td class="  sorting_1">2012-03-20 10:26:13</td>
      <td class=" "><a href="/uploads/comment/file/24/google-qr-code.jpg">google-qr-code.jpg</a></td>
      <td class=" "><center><a href="/companies/12/comments/24" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Delete" height="15px" src="/assets/delete.png"></a></center></td>
    </tr><tr class="odd">
      <td class=" ">
      <img alt="Google-qr-code" height="50" src="/uploads/user/avatar/1/google-qr-code.jpg" width="50">
      </td>
      <td class=" ">Ahmet2</td>
      <td style="overflow: auto;" class=" ">hey</td>
      <td class="  sorting_1">2012-03-20 10:00:02</td>
      <td class=" "></td>
      <td class=" "><center><a href="/companies/12/comments/12" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Delete" height="15px" src="/assets/delete.png"></a></center></td>
    </tr><tr class="even">
      <td class=" ">
      <img alt="Google-qr-code" height="50" src="/uploads/user/avatar/1/google-qr-code.jpg" width="50">
      </td>
      <td class=" ">Ahmet2</td>
      <td style="overflow: auto;" class=" ">test</td>
      <td class="  sorting_1">2012-03-20 10:00:00</td>
      <td class=" "></td>
      <td class=" "><center><a href="/companies/12/comments/11" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Delete" height="15px" src="/assets/delete.png"></a></center></td>
    </tr><tr class="odd">
      <td class=" ">
      <img alt="Google-qr-code" height="50" src="/uploads/user/avatar/1/google-qr-code.jpg" width="50">
      </td>
      <td class=" ">Ahmet2</td>
      <td style="overflow: auto;" class=" ">test</td>
      <td class="  sorting_1">2012-03-20 09:59:41</td>
      <td class=" "></td>
      <td class=" "><center><a href="/companies/12/comments/10" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Delete" height="15px" src="/assets/delete.png"></a></center></td>
    </tr></tbody></table><div class="dataTables_info" id="comment_info"></div><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers" id="comment_paginate"><a tabindex="0" class="first paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" id="comment_first">First</a><a tabindex="0" class="previous paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" id="comment_previous">Previous</a><span><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_active">1</a><a tabindex="0" class="paginate_button">2</a></span><a tabindex="0" class="next paginate_button" id="comment_next">Next</a><a tabindex="0" class="last paginate_button" id="comment_last">Last</a></div></div>
```

Comment: If the problem is on the client, show the client code, not your server-side source code.

Comment: can you provide the css?

Comment: Are you setting a width on the cells in question?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby, as Diodeus asked: please post the html as seen by the browser (`view source `).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WNQt5G4d is the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have one long word pushing out your table. You can use the CSS `word-wrap` property on your table cells. This will tell any words that are too long to break in the middle instead of pushing it's containers boundaries.

```
#comment td{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Edit, you might also have to set a width on your #comment element. Set it to 100% if it's going to fill it's entire container. You might also want to set a specific width on the comment `td`.

Comment: Take into account that 'word-wrap' is a CSS3 property, which means it will not work on old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each comment in an element (not `TD` table-cell itself) with `overflow: auto` to force showing local scrollbar in case of comment is too long.

Comment: Im using datatables from datatable.net dont think it supports scrollbar width

Comment: Don't you have access to table-row template?

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to help if we could take a look at your CSS coding.
You may wanna try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the specific element containing to comments.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp